# VS Blazor Server App Template: Server to Client SignalR Communication

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

Since blazer server already establish a signalr connection with it's client, without creating new signalr connection is there any simple way for server to tap in blazorhub and push notification to client?

Comment: answer can found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#in-memory-state-container-service-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call StateHasChanged the DOM is updated if needed.

You can trigger this update with a timer or with some other events.

```
public async Task NewMessageAsync(Message message, CancellationToken cancel)
{
      if (_tenant.MessageMatchTemplate(message, _template))
      {
          messagesDisplayList.Add(message.data);
          await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
      }
}
```

Full chat example here

https://github.com/iso8859/ThreadMessaging

Comment: I just so in love the Blazor server design. Replace JavaScript API call with real time SignalR connection by design is so god damn brilliant. Thanks!